# How do I get back the state variables on the other side?

Tags: ember.js

If I have the following code for my state:

```
var year    = this.get('year').get('number');
var month   = this.get('month').get('label').toLowerCase();

App.get('router').transitionTo('volumeElaboration', { month: month, year: year });
```

How would I go about getting the month and year variables once the state has changed? My state itself is defined like so:

```
volumeElaboration: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/volume/:month/:year',
    connectOutlets: function(router)
    {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('volumeElaboration');
    }
}),
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question isn't clear. I want to get back the month and year variables now in my view. Something like: this.get('month')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a second variable available in the `connectOutlets` call. That variable is the context.

```
volumeElaboration: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/volume/:month/:year',
    connectOutlets: function(router, context)
    {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('volumeElaboration', context);
    }
}),
```